# Class derived from collections.Counter looses values when pickled

Tags: python, counter, pickle, dask

I want to create a class that works like a counter, but has some extra features. Here's a stripped-down version:

```
from collections import Counter
import pickle

class DerivedCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, *args, capacity: int = 10):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._capacity = capacity

dc = DerivedCounter(capacity = 200)
print("Original", dc._capacity)
print("Pickled", pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(dc))._capacity)
```

When using Dask, this object gets pickled and unpickled. Unfortunately, the value of _capacity is lost on the way, and the output is:

```
Original 200
Pickled 10
```

It seems to use the default value instead of the one chosen when creating the object! When I inherit from dict instead of Counter, I do get this:

```
Original 200
Pickled 200
```

So what's so weird about Counter, and how could I work around that?

Best, Boris

Comment: `collections.Counter` contains a `.__reduce__()` method that explicitly specifies what data is to be saved when pickling - and that doesn't include any attributes you might add.  You'd need to override that method.

Comment: @jasonharper you should write an answer about it, it seems there are none on SO which specifically deal with `Counter.__reduce__`. I've coded a working solution thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jasonharper, many thanks for the explanation in your comment! The Counter's `__reduce__` function seems indeed to be a bit special. For example, the functions `__getstate__`, `__setstate__`, `__getnewargs__` and `__getnewargs_ex__` are not being called. So, re-redefining the `__reduce__` seems to be the way to go.

Here's the redefinition that you're referring to:
[https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/**init**.py#L697](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L697)

It's not clear to me, why Counter would need this. In fact, restoring its `__reduce__` function to the one of dict seems to solve my problem:

```
from collections import Counter
import pickle

class DerivedCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, *args, capacity: int = 10):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._capacity = capacity

    def __reduce__(self):
        return dict.__reduce__(self)

dc = DerivedCounter(capacity = 200)
print("Original", dc._capacity)
print("Pickled", pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(dc))._capacity)
```

Now the output is what I would expect:

```
Original 200
Pickled 200
```

And the restored object seems to be fully intact regarding its function as a Counter. So maybe the redefinition of `__reduce__` in Counter is obsolete, if not harmful?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are pickling the entire class. It get's called fresh when you unpickle it.

```
from collections import Counter
import pickle

class DerivedCounter(Counter):
    def __init__(self, *args, capacity=10):
        print('dc', args, capacity)    #<---add this line

        Counter.__init__(self, *args)
        self._capacity = capacity

dc = DerivedCounter(capacity=200)
print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(dc))._capacity)

#>>> dc () 200
#>>> dc ({},) 10
#>>> 10
```

Maybe pickling `dc.__dict__` would be sufficient.

```
from collections import Counter
import pickle

class Pickler:
    @property       
    def pickled(self):
        return pickle.dumps(self.__dict__)

    def __init__(self, pickled=None):
        if pickled:
            self.cucumbered(pickled)

    def cucumbered(self, pickled):
        self.__dict__ = pickle.loads(pickled)
        return self


class DerivedCounter(Counter, Pickler):
    def __init__(self, *args, capacity=10, pickled=None):
        Counter.__init__(self, *args)
        Pickler.__init__(self, pickled)
        if not pickled:
            self._capacity = capacity


dc = DerivedCounter(capacity=200)
print(dc.cucumbered(dc.pickled)._capacity)    # 200

dc2 = DerivedCounter(pickled=dc.pickled)    
print(dc2._capacity)                          # 200
```

Comment: But why does it behave well, if I derive it from dict instead of Counter?
Unfortunately, I cannot make Dask call a custom pickled function when I pickles the stuff...

Comment: Because dict is just a container of values, whereas your class has a constructor, methods, etc.. Think of it like this. You can mail a letter. You cannot mail the post office.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `copyreg`(build-in module [copyreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#copyreg.pickle)) module to do what you want.
It will copy all the state in the instance you create.

```
class DerivedCounter(Counter):
def __init__(self, capacity: int = 10, *args):
    print('init')
    super().__init__(*args)
    self._capacity = capacity  

def pickle_dc(d):
    print("pickling a DerivedCounter instance...")
    return DerivedCounter, (d._capacity, { key: value for key, value in 
dc.items()})

copyreg.pickle(DerivedCounter, pickle_dc)
dc = DerivedCounter(200, {'a':10})
print(dc._capacity)
a = pickle.dumps(dc)

print(pickle.loads(a)._capacity)
c = pickle.loads(a)
```

In pickle doc we can see pickle load won't invoke `__init__` [doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances)

Comment: Yes, it says: "__init__() method is usually not invoked. The default behaviour first creates an uninitialized instance and then restores the saved attributes."

And it seems that a class inheriting from dict gets its attributes restored, while a class inheriting from Counter doesn't, which is weird!

Comment: Regarding copyreg - I don't want to mess with Dask's way of pickling things, that would be open heart surgery I'm afraid ;-)